# Sending information through bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

Currently I am working on a project that requires me to send information through bluetooth from one iOS device to another, for example one user types a sentence and they will be able to send it to a second user all through bluetooth. Would I use CoreBluetooth for this?

Answer (score 2):

CoreBluetooth is for low-level Bluetooth connectivity, it's not very useful for connectivity between two iOS devices.
Take a look at the Multipeer Connectivity framework, there's a quick tutorial on Hacking With Swift on how to implement a peer to peer ZeroConf connection between two iOS devices:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/25/overview